# Which of the methods of turning on Data Protection on iOS are necessary?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsfilemanager, data-protection

I'm interested in using data protection in my iOS app.  There seem to be three places I can do this:

1. In the App ID in the developer centre.
2. In the entitlements plist
3. By using [`[-NSFileManager setAttributesOfItemAtPath:error:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/setAttributes%3aofItemAtPath%3aerror%3a)

I've read the documentation that I can find, but none of it tells me which of these I need to do.  If I do 1, does that turn it on for the whole app?  Can I do 3 without doing 1?  Do I need to do 2 at all?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've had the following answers from Apple:

> If I do 1, does that turn it on for the whole app?

Yes.  It becomes the default data protection for all file system objects your app creates.

> Can I do 3 without doing 1?

Yes.  This is useful if you want protect just one file.

You can also do 1 and 3, that is, use 1 to set the default and 3 to override that default for certain files.

> Do I need to do 2 at all?

No.  Once you do 1, the value ends up in your provisioning profile, which is then merged into your code signing entitlements at build time.

Comment: The exceptions that I have seen for 1 are: `NSURLCache` and Core Data stores (which need the `NSPersistentStoreFileProtectionKey` option set).